# Remote HTTP monitoring

Tags: monitoring

Are there any simple web based http monitoring open source tools I can run to remotely monitor web servers and such?  I know about Nagios but I want a light install and unsure what exactly I should install (plugins etc.?)

Comment: Have you considered just using something like [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/)? That's about as light an install you can get.

Answer (score 0):

> simple web based http monitoring

Here is a Perl script for simple monitoring: http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/qt/servicemonitor.htm

But if you only need http monitoring (as opposed to monitoring server data like CPU usage or disk i/o) you can avoid any installation by using a hosted service like Pingdom.

Actually, it is even *better* to monitor externally in this case, since internal monitoring does not account for data center network issues (such as the [1and1 downtime](http://blog.alertfox.com/2011/09/1and1-down-external-website-monitoring.html) last week).